# C - output reverse of main arguments

Tags: c, string, parameter-passing, program-entry-point

Write a program that displays the characters of its command line arguments in reverse order. (if the command line arguments are "one" and "two", the program should display "owt eno"

My program works. However, after giving the result it crashes ("the program has stopped working").

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * myReverse ( char * string );

int main ( int argc, char *argcv[] )
{
  char args[argc-2];
  int i = argc - 1;

  while ( i > 0 )
  {
    char * rev = myReverse (argcv[i--]);
    puts(rev);
  }

  return 0;
}

char * myReverse ( char * string )
{
  int i = strlen(string) - 1 ;
  char * revString;
  int pos = 0;

  revString[i+1] = '\0';

  while ( i >= 0 )
  {
    revString[i] = string[pos++];
    i--;
  }

  return revString;
}
```

Comment: `char * revString;` You never initialize or allocate any memory for this. And you return a local var.

Comment: `revString[i+1] = '\0';` performes a write to an unitialized variable `char * revString;`.

Comment: Why not just print it out reversed instead of creating a new reversed string?

Comment: @ErikW that makes sense :D

Comment: @JohnnyMopp what's the problem with returning a local var?

Comment: @Tom  If you need to output a string in the reversed order there is no need to reverse the string itself. Just output it in the reverse order.

Comment: Since this is a pointer which you will presumably allocate with `malloc`, my comment about the local var doesn't apply.

Comment: @Tom-- no problem returning local variables; the problem would be returning a _pointer_ to a local variable, since local variables no longer exist after the function returns. This is not the case here.

Comment: Your compiler should be complaining that `args` is unused.  You could simply modify the argument strings in place, rather than attempt and fail to allocate new memory, etc.

Comment: @DavidBowling would the use of "static" make the job? Would it be sensible?

Comment: Why allocate *anything*? Just accomplish what was asked for. [For example, here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ebafa745bddd192). Nowhere in your requirements is anything stating you have to actually "reverse" any strings; the requirement is to *output* the arguments (and their content) in reverse *order*.

Comment: Thank you all. Both those who solved the problem I had in my program and those who pointed out the more sensible solution. I learned in both cases.

Comment: Agree with @WhozCraig, if the goal is simply to display the characters in reverse order. If the desire is to save a reversed copy of a string, I would favor declaring an array to receive the copy in `main()` and passing it into `myReverse()`, so that the function could be used to make copies of multiple strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to allocated memory for your strings. You can solve this by using stack allocated arrays or by allocating memory on the heap.  I solved the issue by allocating memory on the heap by calling `malloc`.

Update: pointer checked against null

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // This changed

char * myReverse ( char * string );

int main ( int argc, char *argcv[] )
{
  char args[argc-2];
  int i = argc - 1;

  while ( i > 0 )
  {
    char * rev = myReverse (argcv[i--]);
    if(ptr != NULL) {
       puts(rev);
       free(rev);  // This changed
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

char * myReverse ( char * string )
{
  int i = strlen(string) - 1 ;
  char * revString = malloc(i + 1);  // This changed
  if(ptr == NULL) return NULL;

  int pos = 0;

  revString[i+1] = '\0';

  while ( i >= 0 )
  {
    revString[i] = string[pos++];
    i--;
  }

  return revString;
}
```

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` always is `1`, which means that it in useless in this case. I suggest you to remove it

Comment: Good for freeing the allocated memory.   Not so good for not checking that memory was allocated before using it.

Comment: Thank you guys for the feedback, fixed

Answer (score 1):

> Write a program that displays the characters of its command line
>   arguments in reverse order

As I'm also a beginner may I write the program?:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    for (int i = argc; i-- > 1; )
    {
        size_t n = strlen(argv[i]);
        while (n != 0) putchar(argv[i][--n]);
        putchar(' ');
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned in the comments, you never initialize (allocate memory space) for `revString`.

Since it is a `char` pointer, you actually need to allocate memory for storing all the character values of the array.

Replace the declaration of `revString` with:

```
char * revString = malloc(strlen(string)+1);
```

and it will work.

Comment: And then note that the allocated memory should be freed.